# What items should be passed for the remove_from_cart event in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-4

In GA4, with the remove_from_cart event, do we pass the item removed in the items array or do we pass the remaining cart?  This is very unclear from the documentation.

Tried passing both but are not sure which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's for removed item, not for the rest of cart. Please check https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735?hl=en, you can see the event in "For online sales" section.
remove_from_cart:   a user removes items from a cart